# Select Distinct Case Query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, group-by, count

I have the below query

```
SELECT Distinct dbo.WSUS_ComputerUpdateStatusWithApprovals.fulldomainname AS [Computer Name]
  ,dbo.WSUS_ComputerUpdateStatusWithApprovals.title AS [Update Title]
  ,count((case when (DATEDIFF(day, [ArrivalDate], GetDate())) > '0' and (DATEDIFF(day, [ArrivalDate], GetDate())) < '31' Then '' End)) AS 'Green'
  ,count((case when (DATEDIFF(day, [ArrivalDate], GetDate())) > '31' and (DATEDIFF(day, [ArrivalDate], GetDate())) < '91' then '' End)) AS 'Yellow'
  ,count((case when (DATEDIFF(day, [ArrivalDate], GetDate())) > '90' then '' End)) AS 'Red'
  ,DATEDIFF(day, [ApprovalCreationDate], GetDate()) AS 'DaysOldSinceApproval'
FROM dbo.WSUS_ComputerUpdateStatusWithApprovals 
WHERE dbo.WSUS_ComputerUpdateStatusWithApprovals.IsApproved = 1 
Group by dbo.WSUS_ComputerUpdateStatusWithApprovals.fulldomainname 
,[ArrivalDate] 
,dbo.WSUS_ComputerUpdateStatusWithApprovals.ApprovalCreationDate
,dbo.WSUS_ComputerUpdateStatusWithApprovals.title
ORDER BY  dbo.WSUS_ComputerUpdateStatusWithApprovals.fulldomainname ASC
```

The result set comes out like this:

[image: Results]

Where I would want it to say Computer Name and a Total count for each Green, Yellow, Red.  So in this case, Computer Name, Green = 3, Yellow = 1 and Red = 1.  I included the title and days old to show additional information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I followed you correctly, you just need to change the `group by` clause so it generates one row per `fulldomainname`:

```
select 
    fulldomainname AS [Computer Name],
    sum(case when datediff(day, [ArrivalDate], GetDate()) between 1  and 30 then 1 else 0 end) AS Green,
    sum(case when datediff(day, [ArrivalDate], GetDate()) between 30 and 90 then 1 else 0 end) AS Yellow,
    sum(case when datediff(day, [ArrivalDate], GetDate()) > 90              then 1 else 0 end) AS Red
from dbo.WSUS_ComputerUpdateStatusWithApprovals 
where IsApproved = 1 
group by fulldomainname 
order by fulldomainname ASC
```

Note that I changed the conditional aggregation logic to use `sum()` rather than `count()`, because it seems easier to follow.

Comment: Thank you, that works very well but the table I am pulling from seems to have duplicate entries for all the windows updates, is there a way to filter out the first occurrence of each "title"? So there are 2+ rows for each of the Windows Update Entries.

Comment: So not exactly duplicate rows, they have a column called Approval ID that is different between the two rows.  This is why Select Distinct isn't working.